# PHP - ip2long not converting properly

Tags: php

I'm currently trying to learn php and am having trouble with the ip2long() function.

```
$ipToConvert = '46.21.13.34';
$ip = ip2long($ipToConvert);

echo $ipToConvert;
echo $ip;
```

The expected result is that the first echo displays 46.21.13.34 and the second echo displays 46211334.

The result I am getting is that the first one does indeed display 46.21.13.34, the second echo however displays 773131554.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how `ip2long` works. It converts the 4 bytes to a long value.

So for example `a.b.c.d` gets converted to `(a << 24) + (b << 16) + (c << 8) + d`

What you probably want is removing the dots from the string and converting the result to a number:

```
intval(str_replace('.', '', $ip));
```

Or, since the result could possibly overflow, convert to a float

```
floatval(str_replace('.', '', $ip));
```

Comment: `(float)` typecasting will be a better option; as for some IPs , the number will go out of `int` range in PHP. +1

Comment: An integer is not enough. If the IP is past PHP Max integer value it will be negative. I think   it's better to keep it as string. But that is only my opinion. Edit. My phone updated the page now and I see that I'm late to the party....

Comment: Unless you do some math operations on the address it makes no sense to convert it to int.